# Getting error "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'"

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

I just write compile com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3 and I got error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Without any extra codes. Just compile and and I got error. And red line shows com.android.support.appcompat-v7:25.3.1 (support library must use the exact same version). What does this mean?

```
<?apply plugin: 'com.android.application' android 
{ compileSdkVersion 25 buildToolsVersion '25.0.2' defaultConfig { applicationId "com.example.mayur.mahadev" 
minSdkVersion 22 targetSdkVersion 25 versionCode 1 versionName "1.0" testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" } buildTypes { release { minifyEnabled false proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
packagingOptions { exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' 
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' exclude 
'META-INF/LICENSE' exclude 
'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' } }
 dependencies { compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espres‌​so-core:2.2.2', { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' })compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2' compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1' testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' } 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'?>
```

Comment: Hi. Do post your complete gradle file.

Comment: Hi a b. Please *edit* the post and paste the gradle files so the community would be able to read it properly. :)

Comment: Ohh ok ok thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the multidex support to your app because you are compiling more than 64k methods, refer to [this official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=en) for more details.

You have to add these two lines in your gradle at app level:

```
    android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Add this line to your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And add these code snipet to all your activites:

```
 @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
```

Comment: Not working Compile shows red line  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'